# How to increase size in this HTML?

Tags: html, size

[img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w6uV3.png)
please see this image, you can see there is a small logo on the left, I want to increase its size how to do that? The code is in the image and in text format here too. Please help me fix it.

```
<div class="topbar-wrapper">
<header class="header2">
<div class="top-wrappers">
<nav class="top-gridnav">
<div id="breakingnews"><span class="breakhead"><i class="fa fa-circle-o-notch fa-spin"></i> Trending</span>
<div id="adbreakingnews"><span>No result!</span></div></div>
<div class="top-navigation-right">
<div class="top-social-wrapper">
<div class="social-icon"><a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCzwyjkovb2EkvTs7hgDNTkQ" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-youtube-play"></i></a></div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
</nav>
</div>
</header>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Use **font-size** property in style attribute or change it by css.
I have added as 20px.
Hope that Helps.

```
<div class="topbar-wrapper">
<header class="header2">
<div class="top-wrappers">
<nav class="top-gridnav">
<div id="breakingnews"><span class="breakhead"><i class="fa fa-circle-o-notch fa-spin"></i> Trending</span>
<div id="adbreakingnews"><span>No result!</span></div></div>
<div class="top-navigation-right">
<div class="top-social-wrapper">
<div class="social-icon"><a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCzwyjkovb2EkvTs7hgDNTkQ" target="_blank"><i style="font-size:20px" class="fa fa-youtube-play"></i></a></div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
</nav>
</div>
</header>
</div>
```